# how to add an existing_model as many-to-many relation to a dummy_mode in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I am trying to make a testcase within laravel.

1. I have a **fake** *User* model (which dosent exists in DB), and creating it using `faker->make`,
2. and a **real** *Role* model which exists in DB,

these two have a *many-to-many* relationship

in my testcase, i am going to associate them like here  :

```
public function testAccess()
{
        $user = factory(\App\User::class)->make();
        $supervisionControllerRole = \App\Role::where('name', 'supervision_controller')->first();
        $user->roles->add($supervisionControllerRole);
}
```

since i dont want to save the relation in database, i am using `add()` instead of `attach()`:

```
$user->roles()->attach($supervisionControllerRole->id);
//resulting database modification.
```

### Problem

my problem is, when i am trying to get the relation **from the model** its ok.

```
var_dump($user->roles->first());
```

but when i am trying to get the relation **Within The Model**, it dosent works.

like here in my `User` Model:

```
public function hasRole($roleName)
{
    $role_id = Cache::tags(['role_id'])->remember($roleName, 24*3600, function () use ($roleName) {
        return \App\Role::where('name', $roleName)->first()->id;
    });
    return $this->roles()->where('role_id', $role_id)->exists();
}
```

> It will `returns false` and trying `$this->roles->count()` results `0`
> from inside of the model.

### My definitions

in `User` model:

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany("App\Role", "role_user")->whereNull("deleted_at")->using("App\RoleUser");
}
```

User Factory:

```
$factory->define(User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'id' => $faker->randomNumber(),
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'email_verified_at' => now(),
        'password' => Str::random(80), // password
        'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
    ];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you call a relationship with parentheses, such as

```php
return $this->roles()->where('role_id', $role_id)->exists();
                   ^^
```

you're accessing a `Builder` query instance which will return info from the database.  But your data is not in the database, so of course it won't find anything when it looks there.

When you directly `add()` the relationship (vs `attach()`), you're inserting into a `Collection` instance, which as you know doesn't affect the database.  This information is saved on the model only and stored in memory.  Hence when you do

```php
var_dump($user->roles->first());
```

it finds the information since it's already in memory.  (You should also be able to call `$user->roles->count()` here and get a non-zero value.)

And since it's in a relationship of the model vs a direct attribute, I don't even think it would update the database if you were to `save()` the model.

You can use the [`contains`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-collections#method-contains) method to perform the first step if you are not storing in the database:

```php
return $this->roles->contains($role_id);
```

Comment: thanks for your response. but do you have a suggestion if i dont want to modify my model with `return $this->roles->contains($role_id);` and writing a testcase. it seems, i have to create a `test_db` but, i am looking for another solution.

Comment: you're not testing against a separate test database?  that explains why you didn't want to save the model to the database.